# Jqtouch and a desktop browser plugin?

Tags: plugins, browser, desktop, jqtouch

Problem: Jqtouch is only for 'small screens' and is optimized for the iPhone.

Question: I'm looking for a jqtouch plugin which makes it 'desktop friendly' by altering whatever is needed.

Possible solution: I realize I could do a redirect to a website on detecting a desktop but I'm sure there is a jquery plugin that's developed to make it desktop browser friendly, I just can't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is cheap but you can check for window.Touch and that will let you know that you are dealing with a touch screen. Even though you can have a touch screen that is a desktop the interface experience is the same then as a mobile.

I use special media queries to detect instead the size of the screen and not the type of device
 http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

```
@import url('./collect-p.css') only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait);

@import url('./collect-l.css') only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape);

@import url('./collect-l.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 1025px);
```

The first query will load a style sheet for an Ipad in portrait
The 2nd query will load a style sheet for an Ipad in landscape
The last query will load a style sheet for any thing else including a regular browser( In my case the layout I made for the tablet is also designed to work well with browsers but you can allways have a sheet just for the desktop)
 I have to say Media Queries are confusing and it is made worse by a lot of the goofy designer blogs out there but they are with out doubt the way to go and will save you frig tons of work in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have helped a lot!

Comment: I am glad it did. It was perfect timing I had just gone through learning this myself!